# Setting asp.net button name and value

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5

It appears that ASP.NET WebForms automatically sets the values of the name and value attributes with the value of the ID attribute for an asp:Button. How dou you set custom values for those attributes? I tried it with
 `MyButton.Attributes["name"] = "CustomName"`

but then i have two name attributes in generated html.

I would like to use custom values to determine which button was clicked during a postback. I don't want to use CommandName or CommandArgument because when a postback occurs I just want to check for name and value. I don't want to care about whether a handwritten input element

(like `<input type="submit" name="buttons" value="abc"></input>`)

caused the postback or a input element generated by asp.net

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to static. However, you need to make sure that ID is unique within a page.

### ASPX

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="CustomButton" Text="abc" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

### Render HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="CustomButton" value="abc" id="CustomButton" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately this requires ASP.NET 4. I use 3.5.